# Fill remaining height of parent after sibling hits min height

Tags: html, css

Title sounds pretty tricky I guess, the thing that I want to achieve is to simply fill exactly remaining height of parent element, here's what I've got, HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="row1"></div>
    <div id="row2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#row1{
    min-height:30px;
    height:10%;
}
#row2{
    height:90%;
}
```

When #row1 hits min-height and stops shrinking #row2 starts getting extra height, how do I make it calculate height correctly without use of javascript (not that I can't code in it, it's just that half of my layout is made in this example and javascript would cause a lot of performance decrease).

Comment: What if `#row1` had a height greater than `min-height`? what then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `calc()`.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p2jee657/)**

```
#row2 {
  max-height: calc(100% - 30px);
  height: 90%;
}
```

Comment: Duuuuuuuuude, I've been trying out flex layouts(learned them from scratch), tried out table layouts, floats, searched through out half the internet and haven't even thought about this simple solution, you have no idea how much you've helped me, how could I've been so blind...THANK YOU!

Comment: @c-smile Those can be fixed with box-sizing:border-box;

Answer (score 0):

Solution with flexes:

```css
#container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
}

#row1{
    min-height:30px;
    height:10%;
    background:red;
}

#row2{
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="row1">row1</div>
    <div id="row2">row2</div>
</div>
```